# How to debug github cli tool in vs code

Tags: github, command-line-interface, vscode-debugger

I want to debug the "gh pr checks" command in vs code. For that I need to first authenticate using "gh auth login" command. But I am not able to figure out how to first login and then debug this command in vscode.

My launch.json file looks like this->

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       
        {
            "name": "gh pr checks",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/cmd/gh",
            "args":[
                "pr",
                "checks",
                " https://github.com/<org>/<repo-name>/pull/19"
            ],
            "cwd": "/path/to/the/sample/repo"
        }
    ]
}
```